# VBA to create new row and delete original rows based on Date criteria

Tags: vba, excel, date, filtering

I hope you can help.

I have an excel sheet see screen shots attached. What I am trying to achieve is this.

I have some duplicate entries in an excel sheet with multiple start dates and end dates. What I am looking for is some code that can identify duplicates, create a new row with the earliest start date available and latest end date available then delete the duplicate rows, leaving the new row

So in screen shot 1.

you can see rows 2 and 3 have an entry for **Jorgen Steen Agnholt** the earliest start date for these entries is **01/04/2016** and the latest end date is **17/06/2016**

Shot 1. 
[image]

What i need is just one row that has the earliest possible start date available and the latest possible start date available.

So those two entries would become one

see screen shot 2.

Shot 2. 
[image]

Like wise with rows 7 to 11 **Andres Nyboe Andersen**

You can see in screen shot 1 he has 5 rows of data and multiple start and end dates, the earliest start date is **14/03/2016** and the latest end date is **07/04/2016** what i need is one row of data that looks like screen shot 3.

Shot 3

[image]

The duplicates have been removed and I have one row with the earliest start date and latest end possible available

I know I don't have any code usually i do have some to leverage, but I am at loss to figure out the best approach perhaps Autofilter? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: For x = LastRow to 2 Step -1 and do a search for Range("B" & x).Value above it and if you find it, then check again until it doesn't find it then use offset to grab the last date and move it up and the delete all non-essential rows.  As for writing the code, SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: You may do that with SQL via ADODB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub ConsolidateDupes()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim r As Long

    Set wks = Sheet1

    lastRow = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For r = lastRow To 3 Step -1
        ' Identify Duplicate
        If wks.Cells(r, 1) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 1) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 2) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 2) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 3) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 3) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 4) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 4) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 5) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 5) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 6) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 6) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 7) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 7) Then
            ' Update Start Date on Previous Row
            If wks.Cells(r, 8) < wks.Cells(r - 1, 8) Then
                wks.Cells(r - 1, 8) = wks.Cells(r, 8)
            End If
            ' Update End Date on Previous Row
            If wks.Cells(r, 9) > wks.Cells(r - 1, 9) Then
                wks.Cells(r - 1, 9) = wks.Cells(r, 9)
            End If
            ' Delete Duplicate
            Rows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! THANK YOU!! A thousand times thank you this is working. Much respect from Dublin Ireland. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not an exact solution to the question, but close.
You can use pivot tables to do most of the work for you.

1. For clarity, include a column in your spread sheet, set to =CONCATENATE(C1, " ", ", A1) to give you the complete name
2. Then, select your table and create a pivot table
3. Use the calculated Name column as rows
4. Use Start Date as column and **Set the value settings to MIN of start date**
5. You need to format the pivot table column as date
6. Do the same thing for End Date but choose **Set the value settings as MAX of end date**
7. Set the format as short date.

What you get out of this is a pivot table 1 row per person with MIN(START) and MAX (END).
You might then use that to do other things as needed.

IF you don't want to use pivot tables and use a VBA Macro or something that is doable too, but this should get you closer much faster than writing that VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL and aggregate functions `MIN` and `MAX`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SqlAggregateFunctionsTest()

    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim objConnection As Object
    Dim objRecordSet As Object

    Select Case LCase(Mid(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".")))
        Case ".xls"
            strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"
        Case ".xlsm", ".xlsb"
            strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;"";"
    End Select

    strQuery = "SELECT [Surname], [First Name], [Place of employment], [Address], [Postcode], [City], [CPR no], " & _
        "MIN([Start date]) AS [Start date], MAX([End date]) AS [End date] " & _
        "FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "GROUP BY [Surname], [First Name], [Place of employment], [Address], [Postcode], [City], [CPR no]"

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.Open strConnection
    Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(strQuery)
    RecordSetToWorksheet Sheets(2), objRecordSet
    objConnection.Close

End Sub

Sub RecordSetToWorksheet(objSheet As Worksheet, objRecordSet As Object)

    Dim i As Long

    With objSheet
        .Cells.Delete
        For i = 1 To objRecordSet.Fields.Count
            .Cells(1, i).Value = objRecordSet.Fields(i - 1).Name
        Next
        .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset objRecordSet
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
```

I tested the code with source data on `Sheet1`:

[image: source]

And I have the output on `Sheet2` as follows:

[image: output]

The only limitation for that method is that ADODB connects to the Excel workbook on the drive, so any changes should be saved before query to get actual results.